# Macro for writing 10^power

Tags: macros, math-operators

Can we define a macro for writing "10^power" using a single command?

like I am using following macros for various units.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand*{\eg}{\emph{e.g.}\@\xspace}
\newcommand*{\ie}{\emph{i.e.}\@\xspace}
\newcommand*{\flow}{$m^3/s$\@\xspace}
\newcommand*{\visc}{$Pa.s$\@\xspace}
\newcommand*{\dens}{$kg/m^3$\@\xspace}
```

so can we do that?

Comment: In math mode or in text? You may also want to look at the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for units (which are traditionally set upright and not in math italics).

Comment: Actually in both, because it is really hectic to write anything like "1.489X10^-15" for 15 to 20 times.

Comment: Then as mentioned use siunitx, then `\num{123.25e-25}` is enough plus you can control from the preamble how the e should work. See the siunitx manual for details

Comment: I'd also rather suggest the `siunitx` package, and then you might introduce some shortcut suiting you. Note that your present definitions of the units in math mode `$...$` are wrong: units must be upright: `$\mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{m}^3$` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\ensuremath" macro
\newcommand\tenpow[1]{\ensuremath{{\times}10^{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$1.487\tenpow{-15}$  1.23\tenpow{45}
\end{document}
```

You're obviously free to come up with another name than `\tenpow` for the LaTeX macro.